# NSOperation using GCD, ensure all on the same thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, nsoperation

I have a 'concurrent' `NSOperation`, and during it's work it uses some controller classes that internally use GCD. When these controller classes return with their completion block, the completion block is on another thread.

I know I could store the current thread in the operation start method and run `performSelectorOnThread:`, but ideally I would like to wrap the completion in a GCD block and dispatch onto the same thread as the operation started on. Is this even possible with GCD, as I can only specify a queue to dispatch to.

What's the best way to bring this work back onto the same thread that the operation started on?   Apart from what I already suggested... unless this is the best way.

Comment: "Same thread that the operation started on" is kind of unusual. If you want control about where a completion block is executed, you'd usually pass a queue (dispatch queue or NSOperation queue) to it.

Comment: My answer explains why I wanted to do it this way, it was about Core Data and threads. Instead I updated code to use NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is really possible/advisable. Since iOS 4 onwards, NSOperation is using GCD  , and as GCD is managing my threads - I don't think I should be keeping references to them.

I did find some util methods for executing blocks of code on a particular thread. See  [Practical Blocks by Mike Ash](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-08-14-practical-blocks.html) or [this article](http://objcolumnist.com/2011/05/03/performing-a-block-of-code-on-a-given-thread/) doing similar thing.

As my goal was to keep my core data calls on the same thread, instead I opted to upgrade my code to use parent/child managed object contexts with NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType, and then used performBlock: on the managed object context to ensure all my call backs on the separate threads got executed correctly by core data.

Answer (score 0):

When the operation is completed the UI update or any other related things has to be done on main thread. The following link might be useful to you about CGD.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/4295/multithreading-and-grand-central-dispatch-on-ios-for-beginners-tutorial

Comment: Thanks, I know about doing UI work on the main thread. But this is not my question. My question is about the best practice for bringing my work back onto the thread I started the operation on.