# Assert same NSThread (NSOperationQueue) is current when NSManagedObjectContext is created and used

Tags: ios, ios8, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nsoperationqueue, nsthread

In order to avoid race conditions around Core Data, different threads should use different `NSManagedObjectContext`s (see e.g. [here](http://duckrowing.com/2010/03/11/using-core-data-on-multiple-threads/)).

To ensure this at runtime I would like to assert before each use of a managed object context that the same thread (or operation queue) is current as was when the managed object context was created. In effect, I would like to assert something like `NSThread.currentThread == storedThread` (or `NSOperationQueue.currentQueue == storedQueue`).

Is it appropriate to check for pointer equality between threads (or operation queues) for the stated purpose? And is there a semantic difference between comparing threads and operation queues, again for this stated purpose? (The Apple documentation for frameworks such as Core Data and UIKit usually explains situations around race conditions in terms of threads, e.g.: "Create a separate managed object context for each *thread* and share a single persistent store coordinator.")

**UPDATE** I've by now learned (from revisiting WWDC 2012 Session 2014 *Core Data Best Practices*) that using a `NSManagedObjectContext` with `NSPrivateThreadConcurrencyType` will probably solve this and is the way to go. However, the question would still seem to apply to the legacy choice  `NSConfinedConcurrencyType`.

**UPDATE** From the WWDC 2014 session on *What's new in Core Data*: the launch argument `-com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1` is by now also supported on iOS and implies pretty much the same assertions that I was aiming at (see [here](http://oleb.net/blog/2014/06/core-data-concurrency-debugging/)).

Comment: Are you really using NSThreads rather than GCD or NSOperationQueue? Really? _Really?_

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using `NSThread`s, @matt; there's no need for your tone.

Comment: There's no tone. I just don't believe it. I'm hoping to find out what the OP is _really_ doing and what the question _really_ is.

Comment: For example, if using GCD, the correct way to do this is by examining the queue with `dispatch_get_specific`.

Comment: "I would like to assert that the same thread is current both at the time when a specific managed object context is created and when it is used." That is an interesting problem, but it is probably rather more profound than the limited question you originally asked. I would suggest that you start all over with a new question (or edit this one).

Comment: I would suggest that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16164879/nsoperation-using-gcd-ensure-all-on-the-same-thread is a duplicate and that the problem is well treated there.

Comment: @matt So I've rephrased the question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relying on Core Data's own assertions turned out to be the way to go (see updated question). By relying on the I no longer need to compare for equality of threads (or other abstractions of "threads") at the application level.

Answer (score 0):

It is my understanding that `isExecuting` just indicates that the thread hasn't been cancelled or finished. As a result, more than one thread will be `isExecuting` at a time.

Your `==` comparison is the one to do.

Comment: `[NSThread currentThread] == thread` definitely *is* thread-safe by definition.